# Get district name from latitude and longitude in php

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I have current latitude and longitude, with this how to get district name or code in php. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=48.283273,14.295041&sensor=false');    
$output= json_decode($geocode);
echo $output->results[0]->formatted_address;
?>
```

This will get complete address in that you just pass lat long in that url

Notes: Api Key is needed.

Comment: Thanks KARAN. It's working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geoplugin`.

Try this once:

```
<?php
    $geoPlugin_array = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=###.###.###.###') );//Replcae ###.###.###.### with your ip address.

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($geoPlugin_array);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Hope this may help you.